# How to send an intent to an activity and read extras from it?

Tags: android, android-intent

There's a service which runs always and listens to some events, will push them into a log someday. I would like to display those events in the main actvity when it's running, but how to send the event details to the activity? You don't receive the intent itself, when you send it to the activity with `Context.startActivity()`, so that you can't retrive the data with `Intent.getXxxExtra()`.
(The activity would "subscribe" and "unsibscribe" to the events in onStart() and onStop() with an intent sent to the service, so that the events wouldn't open the activity if it's not in foreground)
Or is there any other way to send data (20-30 characters long String) from a service to an intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue a Broadcast from your Service and implement a private [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class for message passing between your Service and your main Activity.

Comment: thank you, I'll go with BroadcastReceivers for now, since I am more or less familiar with intents and they look sufficient, but never used Messages and Handlers